# Error: Access Denied when transferring pictures from camera

Tags: windows-7

Why does `Error: MOVOO702.MPG Access Denied` show up when I try to transfer pictures from my camera to my computer? Does it not know how to gain access?

Comment: PLEASE STOP YELLING!

Comment: What is the brand and model of your camera? Does plugging the SD card directly into your computer help?

Answer (score 0):

> **Why does `Error: MOVOO702.MPG Access Denied` show up when I try to transfer pictures from my camera to my computer?**

Possibly because the target location in the filesystem is protected against writing by the currently logged-in user.

Possibly because the image is locked in the camera (using in-camera "lock" features) - normally I wouldn't expect that to prevent reading but it might cause problems if the software is moving rather than copying.

> **Does it not know how to gain access?**

It isn't that your computer doesn't know *how*, more probable that the currently logged-in user doesn't have the required *permissions* to write to the location which your software is attempting to use.

The solution might involve

- Checking the image attributes in-camera.
- Configuring a different target location (e.g. "Libraries -> Pictures")
- Choosing a different software application to copy pictures. (e.g. Picasa)
- Choosing a different method of connecting your camera to your computer
  (e.g. use an SD-card slot in the computer rather than a USB cable)